# SQLite - hex value to char or string

Tags: sqlite, sql-injection

I'm writing a tool to exploit SQL Injections. I'm trying to add support to SQLite now and I'm facing a problem: if I need to insert a string but quotes are escaped in Mysql I can use `0x65...`, or in Postgres `CHR(65)||...`. But in SQLite I can't find any way of doing this without using quotes.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a general solution. You may be able to assemble your string using parlor tricks if it contains the right characters. E.g., `substr(quote(hex(0)),1,1)` will return `"'"`, `upper(substr(typeof(cast(0 as text)),3,1))` will return `"X"`, etc. I doubt you can get the whole alphabet this way, but it might be enough for whatever injection you're planning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an equivalent, however you can check the documentation to see if there is anything you can use:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html